# Regex for Twitter's Mentions

Tags: python, regex, twitter

I'm having trouble with the "official" regex that parse twitter's mentions. (https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/java/src/com/twitter/Regex.java)

This is my code:

```
AT_SIGNS_CHARS = u"@\uFF20"
AT_SIGNS = "[" + AT_SIGNS_CHARS + "]"
mention_pattern = u"([^a-z0-9_!#$%&*" + AT_SIGNS_CHARS + "]|^|(?:^|[^a-z0-9_+~.-])RT:?)(" + AT_SIGNS + "+)([a-z0-9_]{1,20})(/[a-z][a-z0-9_\\-]{0,24})?"

patt = re.compile(mention_pattern)

pr = '@ciao bella'
print patt.findall(pr)
```

Why does it print:

```
[('', '@', 'ciao', '')]
```

instead of:

```
['@ciao']
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are using `findall`, it returns tuples with as many elements as there are capturing groups in the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If instead you use `match` and print `group(0)`, which is the full match irrespective of the separate groups, you will see your desired result:

```
>>> patt.match(pr).group(0)
'@ciao'
```

If you want to use `findall` to find multiple results, you can put an extra set of parenthesis around your pattern so that the complete match is the first element of each tuple in the returned list:

```
AT_SIGNS_CHARS = u"@\uFF20"
AT_SIGNS = "[" + AT_SIGNS_CHARS + "]"
mention_pattern = u"(([^a-z0-9_!#$%&*" + AT_SIGNS_CHARS + "]|^|(?:^|[^a-z0-9_+~.-])RT:?)(" + AT_SIGNS + "+)([a-z0-9_]{1,20})(/[a-z][a-z0-9_\\-]{0,24})?)"

patt = re.compile(mention_pattern)

pr = '@ciao bella :-), 123 @adeu guapa'

>>> print patt.findall(pr)

[('@ciao', '', '@', 'ciao', ''), (' @adeu', ' ', '@', 'adeu', '')]
```

**EDIT**: To find mentions plus latin words

```
AT_SIGNS_CHARS = u"@\uFF20"
AT_SIGNS = "[" + AT_SIGNS_CHARS + "]"
mention_pattern = u"([^a-z0-9_!#$%&*" + AT_SIGNS_CHARS + "]|^|(?:^|[^a-z0-9_+~.-])RT:?)(" + AT_SIGNS + "+)([a-z0-9_]{1,20})(/[a-z][a-z0-9_\\-]{0,24})?"
latin = u'[a-zA-Z]+'
mention_or_latin = "(%s|%s)" % (mention_pattern, latin)
patt = re.compile(mention_or_latin)

pr = '@ciao bella, @adeu guapa'

>>> print patt.findall(pr)
[('@ciao', '', '@', 'ciao', ''), ('bella', '', '', '', ''), (' @adeu', ' ', '@', 'adeu', ''), ('guapa', '', '', '', '')]
```

Comment: Thank you, and if I want to match mentions and normal latin words?

latin = u'[a-zA-Z]+'
total = mention_pattern + '|' + latin

Comment: I've a lot of tweets and I want to delete all words like Emoticons, Smile, non latin words from this tweets.

Comment: See edit. In case that's not what you're looking for, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43093713/edit) your question to include an expanded use case with the expected output.